# How to create a view with case statement?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-view

I have a table "hallowelt" which contains 15 column in which one column name is "month".
how to create a view of the table "hallowelt" in which the months are suitably transformed into a new column SEASON by means of a CASE statement into spring, summer, autumn and winter.

Exemple code:

```
create view  hallo_welt
  SELECT month, as 'season'
    CASE
     when month=3 or month<=5 then 'Frühling'
     when month=6 or month<=8 then 'sommer'
     when month=9 or month<=11 then 'Herbst'
     when month=12 or month<=2 then 'winter'
     else ''
    END
 from hallowelt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like

```
create view hallo_welt
  SELECT 
    month,
    CASE
     when month in (3,4,5) then 'Frühling'
     when month in (6,7,8) then 'sommer'
     when month in (9,10,11) then 'Herbst'
     when month in (12,1,2) then 'winter'
     else null
    END season
 from hallowelt;
```

Comment: No need for `else null` - that’s the result when none of the case conditions are met. Just leave it out.